# convert a ruby string or integer or float into a javascript or jquery one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, string, integer

in my rails project some of the following code I have in a Google map is:

```
function initialize_google_maps() {
    var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @user.lat %>, <%= @user.lng %>);
    var zoom = <%= @kms_range %> > 9 ? 9 : 10;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
```

etc, etc...

The problem is those:

```
(<%= @user.lat %>, <%= @user.lng %>);
```

How would I convert <%= @user.lat %> and <%= @user.lng %> into a string, so javascript or jquery can understand it?

For ajax reasons, I can't put this code between script tags. I need to make it into a jquery function, assigning the values  <%= @user.lat %> and <%= @user.lng %> into something that jquery can understand.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  var markers = [];

  function initialize_google_maps() {
    var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @user.lat %>, <%= @user.lng %>);
    var zoom = <%= @kms_range %> > 9 ? 9 : 10;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: currentlatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID
        streetViewControl: false
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: currentlatlng, icon:{oppacity:0}});
    map.setCenter(currentlatlng);
    map.setZoom(zoom);

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        strokeOpacity: 0.7,
        radius: <%= @kms_range %>*1000,
    });
    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

  }

  function show_markers() {
    if (markers)
      for(i in markers) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
      }
  }

  function add_marker(location) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    // markers.setVisible(false);
  }

  function initialize_markers() {
    <% (@reviews || []).each do |r| %>
      <% next unless r.lat && r.lng %>
      position = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= r.lat %>, <%= r.lng %>);
      add_marker(position);
    <% end %>
  }

  $(function() {
    initialize_google_maps();
    initialize_markers();
    show_markers();
  });

</script>
```

Comment: wrap them inside `""`

Comment: Tried that, but it's still ruby code, just with quotes around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are a double or int, you don't need to, you can just render them verbatim. If it really is a string and you need a string in js, just put quotation marks in it:

```
var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("<%= @user.lat %>", "<%= @user.lng %>");
```

Edit: according to comments:

```
var map_latitude = <%= at_user.lat %>;
var map_longitude = <%= at_user.lng %>;
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I tried <div id = "user_lat">
var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("<%= at_user.lat %>", "<%= at_user.lng %>")
currentlatlng </div> and I got returned in my browser: var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("48.8051741", "2.1219587") currentlatlng

Comment: Pleaes show your whole code (in the question). I think you are mixing html with javascript. `var currentlatlng = ...` is javascript and needs to be in `<script>` tags.

Comment: Ah! There's the problem. I'm doing stuff with ajax, where stuff between scripts is not executed on a call back. So I have to make a function on the ajax side - basically displaying the map I wish I could show between my script tags. So I'm trying to convert that ruby code to something jquery can understand. i'll edit my question, with the script code. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to display the value of `currentlatlng` in the `user_lat` div?

Comment: Well, ideally if I could assign <%= at_user.lat %> and <%= at_user.lng %> as decimal variables called map_latitude and
map_longitude. That way, I shouldn't run into trouble with these maps - I've realised they're decimal values, which might cause problems if they're strings. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, +1'd you for all your help...I'll mark correct when I get this part (might make the edit myself, unless you want, for future users) but....where do I declare the variables? It doesn't understand the ruby code in my scripts.js file.

Comment: You are using erb, which is a templating language. You specify your html/js code, and you can render the results of ruby expressions into it - once it is at the client, there is no ruby code anymore that gets executed.

Comment: Cheers, thanks. Changed my scripts.js to scripts.js.erb and got an error but I'll figure it out.